# Download apk and start install prompt inside android application

Tags: android

I'm building a private enterprise Android application. My goal is to detect when there is update available and offer user to download it. If user choose to download update file is downloaded and android app install prompt is showed.

I successfully check for update, the problem is that apk file is not downloaded (empty file is created) therefore "There is a problem parsing the package." error is showed in android app install prompt.

Code:

```
public void downloadfileto(String fileurl, String filename) { 
    String myString; 
    try { 
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(filename); 
            try { 
                    URL url = new URL(fileurl); 
                    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection(); 
                    InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream(); 
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8000); 
                    int current = 0; 
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) { 
                            f.write((byte) current); 
                    } 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                    myString = e.getMessage(); 
            } 
            f.flush(); 
            f.close(); 
            install(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

protected void install(String fileName) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(install);
}
```

Function downloadfileto is called with:

```
downloadfileto("http://some-url/ind.apk", "data/data/my.package.name/app.apk");
```

Comment: You are missing the leading '/' in the directory, however you should be discovering the location of your private storage at runtime rather than making assumptions about the directory a given device will assign to you.  Also, you may need to verify if it is possible to install from private storage, vs public storage like the sdcard.  Since you are not using a secured link, you can probably just hand off the URL without needing to download it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, the problem still remains.

Comment: Verify that you can create and write to a file in this location, and use the getFilesDir() or whatever it is method rather than hard coding the path.  You'll need to test on an emulator or use run-as in the adb shell to view files in the private directory.

Comment: I'm testing app on a rooted phone. In DDMS I can see that the file was successfully created in given directory but it's empty (0 bytes big).

Comment: You might add some logging of the reads and writes, and additional check the logcat for exceptions, such as networking on the main thread or missing network permission.

Comment: Can u please help me how you have checked that either update is available if available then download file else not i want same task solution just put any reference tutorial and code here i am also searching google

Comment: @erum-hannan I have versions of app and physical location of apk saved in MySQL database. Android app then sends request to a simple PHP script which responds with latest version and URL to newest apk. Android app then compares if there is a newer version and if true downloads it and offers update to user (check my code in accepted answer)

Comment: @Soriyyx can u please let me know any good tutorial my target is to automatically install  apk file from Service or automatically update apk file i am newbie in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank you all for helping here. I solved the problem by opening php script on server that counts downloads with web view, detecting download, path of download and starting activity to install application.

Name of file is always in form "ind-version.apk" (Example: ind-1-0.apk) and because I get version number of new update when I check for updates I decided to put it in extras and use it to determine file name.

Code:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.helpview);
    showDialog();
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override  
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageFinished(view, url);
             dismissDialog();
         }  
    });

    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String v = extras.getString("v");
            v = v.replace(".", "-");
            Log.i("File", v);

            File loc = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            Log.i("File", loc.toString() + "/ind-" + v + ".apk");

            install(loc.toString() + "/ind-" + v + ".apk");
        }
    });
```

And install:

```
protected void install(String fileName) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(install);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you download successfully, you will not be able to install the APK file, as the installer process will not be able to read the file. Plus, as Chris Stratton points out, your hard-coded path is sloppy (on Android 4.1 and older) and catastrophic (on Android 4.2 and higher).

In terms of the download logic, downloading a byte at a time is unlikely to perform well. Try something like this (for a `File` named `output` and a `URL` named `url`):

```
  HttpURLConnection c=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

  c.setRequestMethod("GET");
  c.setReadTimeout(15000);
  c.connect();

  FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  BufferedOutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

  try {
    InputStream in=c.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer=new byte[8192];
    int len=0;

    while ((len=in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.flush();
  }
  finally {
    fos.getFD().sync();
    out.close();
  }
```