# how to run installed .apk file from inside android application?

Tags: android, path, uri, apk

I need to know how to open .apk file from inside my application. As I know, there is no any file explorer on Android OS, so I should use downloaded and installed program for this. I hope question is understandable. Thanks!

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790048/download-apk-and-start-install-prompt-inside-android-application

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Intent using the action `android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW` and a data URI pointing to the file.

This should open a dialogue asking the user to install the file (and warning them of the permissions it requires).

However - You do not have access to directly install an APK yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean install apk file after downloading, you can use this intent:

```
Intent installIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + apkFilePath),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(installIntent);
```